# Consequences of Deficiency indices theorem (Von Neumann theory)

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T: \operatorname{dom}(T) \rightarrow \scr H$ be a symmetric operator.

1. $T$ admits self-adjoint extensions $\iff$ $d_+ = d_-$, where $d_\pm = \dim  \ker(T^\dagger \pm i \mathbb{I})$
2. If $d_+ = d_-$, $T$ admits as many self-adjoint extensions as the number of unitary operators $U_0 : \ker(T^\dagger -i \mathbb{I}) \rightarrow \ker(T^\dagger +i \mathbb{I}) $

---

A consequence of this theorem is:

$ \operatorname{dom}(T^\dagger) = \overline {\operatorname{dom}(T)}  \oplus \ker(T^\dagger -i \mathbb{I}) \oplus \ker(T^\dagger +i \mathbb{I})$

But I can't see the reason. The only thing I got is $\overline {\operatorname{dom}(T)}$, because $T$ is symmetric and hence $T \subset T^{\dagger \dagger} = \overline T \subset T^\dagger.$
But what about the other two? And why should they be in direct sum ($\oplus$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in\ker(T^\dagger-i I)$, then $T^\dagger x=ix$. If $x$ is also in $\operatorname{dom}(T)$, then
$$
i\|x\|^2=\langle ix,x\rangle=\langle T^\dagger x,x\rangle=\langle x,Tx\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle. 
$$
As $T$ is symmetric, the rightmost term is real; it follow that $x=0$. So
$$
\operatorname{dom}(T)\cap \ker(T^\dagger\pm i I)=\{0\}. 
$$
If $x\in \ker (T^\dagger-i I)\cap\ker(T^\dagger +iI)$, then $T^\dagger x=ix=-ix$, so $x=0$. Then
$$
\overline {\operatorname{dom}(T)}  \oplus \ker(T^\dagger -i \mathbb{I}) \oplus \ker(T^\dagger +i \mathbb{I})
$$
is a direct sum.

The direct sum is inside $\operatorname{dom}(T^\dagger)$ by definition. I don't immediately see the equality, but I assume it has to come from the theorem, as otherwise the extensions wouldn't be what they are.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. The only thing left I’d like to understand is why there are just those three sets in direct sum. I mean.. is this the only possibility to make ${\rm dom}T^\dagger$? Why should this decomposition be a “clever” choice?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that. But it should be clear from the proof of your #2